Why are PNP transistors ON when the base voltage/current is LOW?
I understand that in NPN transistors when the base is higher than 0.7 volts, it allows a large current to flow from the collector to the emitter.
In PNP transistors, the opposite happens.
When a LOW voltage is applied to the base, it allows a large current to pass from the emitter to the collector. I don't understand why.

In the simplest way to describe it, for PNP, the polarity between emitter and base is just the other way around. Its about the polarity and potential (voltage) difference.

"when the base is higher then 0.7 volts" - you understand wrong. It's when the voltage difference between the base and emitter is higher than 0.7 volts.

These diagrams have some labels to help understand what's going on:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The label \$V_{BE}\$ refers to the potential difference between base potential \$V_B\$ and emitter potential \$V_E\$, which in both cases means:
$$ V_{BE} = V_B - V_E $$
The polarity symbols "+" and "−" tell you which terminal has the higher or lower potential, "+" meaning higher, or more positive.
For the NPN transistor \$V_{BE}\$ must be positive for the transistor to be switched on; \$V_{BE}\approx +0.7V\$. By contrast, for the PNP to be switched on, the base must have a lower (or more negative) potential than the emitter; \$V_{BE}\approx -0.7V\$.
The big takeaway here is that it is not absolute base potential \$V_B\$ that determines transistor state, it is base potential \$V_B\$ relative to emitter potential \$V_E\$ that decides whether the transistor is on or off, or somewhere in between. To reiterate, everything depends on \$V_{BE}\$, where \$V_{BE} = V_B - V_E\$.
Your statement (with reference to the PNP variety) "when a low voltage is applied to the base it allows a larger current to pass from the emitter to the collector"  is true to some extent. More correctly it should read "when a low voltage relative to the emitter is applied to the base it allows a larger current to pass from the emitter to the collector".
If a PNP transistor's emitter is held fixed at +5V, in what we call a "common emitter" arrangement, then to switch that transistor on you must apply a potential lower than +5V, to create the condition \$V_{BE}=V_B-V_E=-0.7V\$. This is shown on the right:

simulate this circuit
Note: in a common emitter scenario we usually don't apply potentials directly to the base. Instead we use a resistor (R2 and R4 above) to pass some current, and allow the transistor's base-emitter junction (which behaves just like a silicon diode) to develop its own potential difference of 0.7V, just as any diode would. If we were to directly apply, say, +2.5V to the base in either scenario above, we would likely destroy the transistor.
The ammeters show significant current flowing, indicating that both transistors are indeed "on". Notice how the voltmeters are connected to show the potential difference between base and emitter, and both show +0.7V or so. Notice also that on the left, for the NPN transistor, base is higher in potential than the emitter \$V_B > V_E\$, but the for the PNP transistor on the right, base potential is lower than the emitter, \$V_B < V_E\$.
I'll redraw the same circuit with voltmeters VM3 and VM4 to show absolute base potential. I've removed voltage sources V1 and V2 to make space, but the ground and \$+5V\$ node labels have the same effect as voltage sources in the CircuitLab simulator:

simulate this circuit
By "absolute" I mean "with respect to ground, 0V". It is clear that the NPN transistor's base potential is \$V_B\approx +0.7V\$, to be switched on, as you expect.
However, for the PNP transistor to switch on, its base has potential is \$V_B\approx +4.3V\$. This makes sense, because as I described above, base potential must be lower than emitter potential:
$$ V_B = +5V - 0.7V = +4.3V $$
To switch the PNP transistor off, you must make \$V_{BE}\$ near zero, which means raising its base potential to \$V_B=+5V\$, for \$V_{BE} = V_B - V_E = (+5V) - (+5V) = 0V\$. I do that here, on the right, using another 5V source V3, but to switch off the NPN I simply connect the base to 0V to make \$V_{BE}=0V\$:

simulate this circuit

The voltage isn't "low".
In both NPN and PNP cases there must be enough voltage to hit the Vbe forward bias voltage so enough base current passes through B-E junction.
If you think of the B-E junction as a diode, the polarity of the diode is just opposite between NPN and PNP junctions.
Which basically leads to how you usually see the transistors being used. For NPN, you ground the emitter, and apply positive bias from e.g. MCU to turn transistor on. For PNP, you connect emitter to MCU supply voltage, and apply negative bias by setting MCU pin low to turn on the transistor.

While your answer isn't wrong, it really only applies to a narrow range of transistor applications.

Trying to see the brilliant idea
Your question is highly relevant, as it delves into foundational circuit arrangements like complementary amplifier stages, high- and low-side switching circuits, common base configurations, and more, that are essential building blocks in many electronic systems.
However, to answer it, we don't need to delve into the specifics of particular circuit implementations. Instead, let's focus on the core idea that is very simple and intuitive.
For this purpose, it is sufficient to simply represent the input of the controlled device (FET, BJT, etc.) with a simple voltmeter, and ignore everything beyond that point. The voltmeter plays the role of a load with respect to the input voltage source; hence the name "Vout".
Exploring the circuit
Positive input voltage
Devices that require a positive input voltage (NMOS, NPN etc.) are the most convenient to control, as we prefer to work with this polarity.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Vin = 0 V

simulate this circuit
Vin = 10 V

simulate this circuit
Vin = 0 ÷ 10 V

Negative input voltage
For this reason, devices requiring a negative input voltage (PMOS, PNP etc.) are less desirable.

simulate this circuit
Vin = 0 V

simulate this circuit
Vin = -10 V

simulate this circuit
Vin = -10 ÷ 0 V

Complementary positive input voltage
To control a device with a negative input voltage  (PMOS, PNP etc.) using a positive voltage, we can shift the input voltage positively using a bias voltage source Vbias (in practical circuits, the power supply Vee serves as such a source). In this way, we control the device not directly with the input voltage, but with its complement to Vbias.
Vin = 0 V: For this reason, in the curcuit below, when the true input voltage Vin is 0 V, the input voltage of the device is Vbias - Vin = 10 V...

simulate this circuit
Vin = 10 V: ...and vice versa, if Vin = 10 V, Vout = 0 V.

simulate this circuit

